# Swift : Programatically Create a UIButton with Some Specific Font And Size

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to create a basic `UIButton` programmatically. For example, in my view controller five `UIButton`s will be created dynamically in the same row and its layout or properties are set for some color, font, and size.

And I also need to add action method for a specific button.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: finally you need action method only for buttons ?

Comment: yes i need @vaibhav

Comment: Why did you rollback all of the grammar and formatting fixes I made to your post?

Answer (score 1):

Create `uibuttons` and add them inside main view see example below.

```
class yourClassName: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // here method CGRectMake defines x, y, width, height
        var btnOne = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        var btnOne = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))

        self.view.addSubview(btnOne) // add button inside view 
        self.view.addSubview(btnOne) // add button inside view 

        // using selector you must specify a method for each button
        btnOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.actionOne), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        btnTwo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.actionTwo), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}
```

---

**Actions methods:**

```
func actionOne(sender : UIButton) {
    print("button one tapped")
}

func actionTwo(sender : UIButton) {
    print("button second tapped")
}
```

Comment: Why would you create outlets if it is all being done in code?

Comment: @rmaddy as per your recommendation see my edited ans .. :)

Comment: Yeah @vaibhav this one is also help me a lot Thanks

Comment: @NilRathod welcome! ..i think its an easiest one to achieve you must do some search before asking here and then share your problem if encountered i recomend you to read [swift programing language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) before you do you do some practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it programmatically, you might think along the following lines:

Create your buttons in a for... loop in viewDidLoad() (or elsewhere, depending on your requirements):

```
    let buttonWidth : CGFloat = self.view.frame.width / 10
    let buttonHeight : CGFloat = 50

    for count in 0..<10 {
        let newButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(count) * buttonWidth, y: 50), size: CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)))
        newButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        newButton.setTitle("Button #\(count)", for: UIControlState.normal)
        newButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        newButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 10)
        newButton.tag = count
        self.view.addSubview(newButton)
    }
```

Then you can implement the selector buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) as follows, retrieving the button's tag so you can tailor the action (via a switch statement, for example):

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) -> Void {
    print("\(sender.tag) was tapped!")

    // Do something more interesting based on the tag here...
}
```

This allows you to set up a lot of button actions without a lot of different selectors. Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah Thanks @Sparky

Answer (score 0):

```
 let bacViewOne=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(20, 60 , 130, 130))
            bacViewOne.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            bacViewOne.layer.cornerRadius=5.0
            btn1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "new.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn1.frame = CGRectMake((bacViewOne.frame.size.width-90)/2, 5 , 90, 90)
            //btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            btn1.tag = 1
            btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.dashboard(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            bacViewOne.addSubview(btn1)
            self.view.addSubview(bacViewOne)

            let l1 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((bacViewOne.frame.size.width-90)/2, 100, 90, 21))

            l1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            l1.textColor = UIColor(red: 41/255.0, green: 43/255.0, blue: 64/255.0, alpha: 1)
            l1.text = "Dashboard"
            //l1.font = UIFont (name: "BakerSignetBT-Roman", size: 15)
            bacViewOne.addSubview(l1)
            l1.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)



            var bacViewT=UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            bacViewT .frame = CGRectMake(20, 240, 130, 130)
            bacViewT.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            bacViewT.layer.cornerRadius=5.0
            btn3 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            btn3.setImage(UIImage(named: "Usernew.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn3.frame = CGRectMake((bacViewT.frame.size.width-90)/2, 5, 90, 90)
//            btn3.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255.0, green: 43/255.0, blue: 64/255.0, alpha: 1)
            btn3.tag = 2
            btn3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.userExpenses(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            bacViewT.addSubview(btn3)

            self.view.addSubview(bacViewT)

            let l2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((bacViewT.frame.size.width-100)/2, 100, 100, 21))

            l2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            l2.textColor = UIColor(red: 41/255.0, green: 43/255.0, blue: 64/255.0, alpha: 1)
            l2.text = "User Expense"
            //l2.font = UIFont (name: "BakerSignetBT-Roman", size: 15)
            bacViewT.addSubview(l2)
            l2.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
            //7


            let bacViewTh=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(170, 60, 130, 130))
            bacViewTh.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            bacViewTh.layer.cornerRadius=5.0
            btn7 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            btn7.setImage(UIImage(named: "events.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn7.frame = CGRectMake((bacViewTh.frame.size.width-90)/2, 5, 90, 90)
            btn7.tag = 3
            btn7.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.upcomingEvents(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            bacViewTh.addSubview(btn7)


            let l3 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((bacViewTh.frame.size.width-100)/2, 100, 100, 21))

            l3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            l3.textColor = UIColor(red: 41/255.0, green: 43/255.0, blue: 64/255.0, alpha: 1)
            l3.text = "Upcoming Events"
            //l3.font = UIFont (name: "BakerSignetBT-Roman", size: 15)
            bacViewTh.addSubview(l3)
            l3.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
            self.view.addSubview(bacViewTh)
            //8

            let bacViewF=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(170, 240, 130, 130))
            bacViewF.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            bacViewF.layer.cornerRadius=5.0
            btn9 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            btn9.setImage(UIImage(named: "Location.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn9.frame = CGRectMake((bacViewF.frame.size.width-90)/2, 5, 90, 90)
            btn9.tag = 4

            btn9.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.userLocations(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            bacViewF.addSubview(btn9)
            self.view.addSubview(bacViewF)

            let l4 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((bacViewF.frame.size.width-100)/2, 100, 100, 21))

            l4.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            l4.textColor = UIColor(red: 41/255.0, green: 43/255.0, blue: 64/255.0, alpha: 1)
            l4.text = "User Locations"
            bacViewF.addSubview(l4)
            l4.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
```

Comment: Thanks And m Remove Your Minus Point for someone add @Yuvarah M